# Can't run monkeyrunner script - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad level

Tags: python, android, monkeyrunner

I tried this but it shows me the middle finger:

> ~/Software/android-sdk-linux_x86-1.6_r1/tools$ sudo ./monkeyrunner -v
>   help.py Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Bad level "help.py"     at
>   java.util.logging.Level.parse(Level.java:336)     at
>   com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions.processOptions(MonkeyRunnerOptions.java:130)
>   at
>   com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:192)

It is on a freshly installed java, jdk, jre, Eclipse, AndroidSDK, ADT

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why sudo ?
You shouldn't use it.
The other problem is that you are missing the log level for -v:

```
Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

    -s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
    -p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
    -v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)
```

Also, be sure you have `help.py` in your current working directory or specify its path.

Comment: Hmm, It is working now. You are right my -v expression isn't correct. Actually the script works. Thank you !